# Stream video in Windows 8 App

Tags: c#, windows-8, windows-runtime

Is there any specific **api or sdk** with help of which I can stream data from a webserver.
I dont want to use **webview** to show **youtube** like feature. But direct streaming without webview?
Thanks for any response

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's super easy, just use a `MediaElement` and put the address of your video in the `Source` property, like this:

```
<MediaElement Source="http://media.ch9.ms/ch9/70b1/b49fa0ce-5112-4852-a178-66dda70b70b1/MakerFaire2013NYCEWB_high.mp4" />
```

That's all! Now you can stream any video.